# El cuerpo de la solicitud tiene un formato json no válido - C#

Tags: c#, json, api

estoy tratando de consumir una api, pero me marca error en el formato json
que es el siguiente:

```html
string json = "{\"email_config_id\": 48000043240, \"status\": 2, \"priority\": 1, \"email\":\"mail@mail.com\",\"subject\":\"CUSTOM FIELD TEST\",\"description\":\"Custom field test succesfully\", \"custom_fields\":\"cf_gadget\":\"Custom field\", \"cc_emails\":[\"mail@mail.com\",\"mail@mail.com\"]}";
```

y les enseño el codigo que utilizo:

```html
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://" + fdDomain + ".freshdesk.com" + apiPath);
            //HttpWebRequest class is used to Make a request to a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI).  
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest. 
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest. 
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            string authInfo = apiKey + ":X"; // It could be your username:password also.
            authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

            //Get the stream that holds request data by calling the GetRequestStream method. 
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream. 
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object. 
            dataStream.Close();
```

y el error que me marca en consola es 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se si mi formato json esta mal o algo que me falta por añadirle
cualquier cosa que necesiten estoy al pendiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si desarmas el json con algo de identacion

```
string json = @"{ 
                    email_config_id: 48000043240, 
                    status: 2, 
                    priority: 1, 
                    email: 'mail@mail.com',
                    subject: 'CUSTOM FIELD TEST',
                    description: 'Custom field test succesfully', 
                    custom_fields: 'cf_gadget': 'Custom field', 
                    cc_emails: ['mail@mail.com',"mail@mail.com"]
                }";
```

veras un problema en la definicion del

```
custom_fields: "cf_gadget": "Custom field",
```

si necesitas agregar mas de un valor sera un array con `[ ]`, pero alli no defines la propiedad de forma correcta

porque no creas una clase como ser

```
public class RootObject
{
    public long email_config_id { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string custom_fields { get; set; }
    public List<string> cc_emails { get; set; }
}
```

entonces con la ayuda de [json.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) puedes serializar la clase a json como string

```
RootObject data = new RootObject();
//aqui asignas propiedades

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

asi evitaras problemas en la generacion del json

Comment: Muchas gracias!! de esa forma se soluciono el problema